# MySQL - Rows skipped without reason

Tags: mysql

I wanted to load local date in my SQL-table via the following code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:....' INTO TABLE masterarbeit_db.knotenpunkte_distanz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The table has three columns:

```
Harbour (Integer) ,  JunctionPoint (Integer) , Distance (Integer)
```

The first two columns are the Primary Key. Normally the code works perfect, but now when I'm using it 12 rows are skipped. The data are just numbers. I have already checked, that the Primary Key isn't duplicate. This is a part of the imported data. There are just numbers to import. Curious, that just the number 695 in column **Harbour** is skipped.

```
690  20  7597
692  1   4010
692  3   7330
692  7   3958
692  20  2850
692  21  6126
695  1   7032
695  4   6867
695  7   7076
695  9   5308
695  11  1374
695  20  6825
695  21  2193
698  3   9117
698  2   2852
```

Does anybody know the reason of this problem?

Comment: The LOAD DATA command you are showing doesn't seem to match the data file? In the command you're saying that fields should be terminated by semicolons, in the data they seem to be terminated by tabs, etc.

Comment: Have you also checked the line ending match?

Comment: The data file i'm using was saved in excel with the endig ".csv". When i'm opening the excel-file via the texteditor the data is shown like this:    

1;14;12999    

I know "terminated by semicolons" don't make sense. But i don't understand the fact, that over 12,000 rows are transferd to the sql-table and 12 rows are skipped. I had checked the rows, but there is no difference to the others.